# React - Delete child object from parent object using key name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to filter out unwanted objects from a parent object
But I'm being thrown an error of `TypeError: Cannot delete property 'children' of #<Object>`

Props passed like this:

```
<Column df={["between", "mt-0", "around"]} xl={["center"]}>...</Column>
```

Given to a utility function like this:

```
const Column = props => {
  const x = filterComponentProps(props)
  return stuff
}
```

The inside the utility function anything within the object not matched within `const condition = ["df", "xl"]` is to be removed.

```
export const filterComponentProps = props => {
  let data = props
  console.log(data) 
  // {df: Array(3), xl: Array(1), children: Array(6)}
  // children: (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
  // df: (3) ["between", "mt-0", "around"]
  // xl: ["center"]

  const condition = ["df", "xl"]
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key =>
    !condition.includes(key) ? delete data[key] : key
  ) //ERROR 
  return data
}
```

I set up a test to see if its a problem with the function but it works as expected:

```
const data = {
  df: { name: "Part 1", size: "20", qty: "50" },
  xl: { name: "Part 2", size: "15", qty: "60" },
  children: { name: "Part 2", size: "15", qty: "120" },
}

const condition = ["df", "xl"]

Object.keys(data).forEach(key =>
  !condition.includes(key) ? delete data[key] : key
)

console.log(data)
//{df: {…}, xl: {…}}
//df: {name: "Part 1", size: "20", qty: "50"}
//xl: {name: "Part 2", size: "15", qty: "60"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Destructure the props like this,

```
let data = {...props};
```

create a shallow copy of props, now loop over data and delete the property you want,

```
export const filterComponentProps = props => {
  let data = {...props};     // shallow copy
  const condition = ["df", "xl"]
  Object.keys(data).forEach(key =>
    !condition.includes(key) ? delete data[key] : key
  )
  return data;
}
```

try this, it will work.

Comment: Nail on the head. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you get this error because you try to modify the object which is freezed. If you try the following

```
const data = Object.freeze({
  df: { name: "Part 1", size: "20", qty: "50" },
  xl: { name: "Part 2", size: "15", qty: "60" },
  children: { name: "Part 2", size: "15", qty: "120" },
})
```

you get the same error. Let me know if it's clear.